# does highcharts.js have a debug mode?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Diagnosing syntax errors in highcharts is really difficult, in part because it seems to suppress errors. Is there a debug mode where it doesn't do that?

Comment: I can only find one `try catch` in the whole source, and that only wraps 4 lines of local code. There needs to be something else that's wrong with your code.

Comment: Well, it's failing on the `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({snip})` call, but not posting anything to firebug. I have console.log() calls right before and after that, and the 'after' one is never getting called, so I don't see how it could be my code.

Comment: Is there any way you could post an example of problem code so we can attack your specific problem?

Comment: This is still happening. var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({snip}) will freeze chrome for me if <snip> does not refer to a syntactically perfect  object.  an error, like "couldn't parse snip" would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Necro, but probably still relevant for people who end up on this question: Highcharts >7.0.0 adds the possibility to show render errors on graphs.

From the docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/debugger-mode

The `debugger.js` file which that page talks about can be found on the Highcharts zip under `code/modules`.

Comment: do you know where we can download it? and it is only for version 7? or version 4.2 has this debugger.js?

Comment: In any of the Highcharts packages (which you can get [here](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/download/)), you will find the file under the path I wrote on the answer (`code/modules`). But sadly yes, only versions >7.0.0 have this file on it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't any debug mode. I am using firebug with Firefox (if you are using chrome you can go for the chrome developer tools), and that can show errors associated with the syntax when a chart is not properly rendering.

Here is the link
https://getfirebug.com/downloads

It's like a console appear in the bottom of the web browser showing all the data transactions.